# Convert matlab data in mat file containing many arrays into numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matlab, mat

I have a .mat file with many arrays and try to convert them to numpy arrays but was not successful so far.

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mat = loadmat("FanMap_data.mat")
print(mat.keys())


dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'fanmap', 'fanmap1D'])
```

The file contains two sets of arrays 'fanmap' and 'fanmap1D' of float64 data.

`fanmap` consists of 1 array with shape(1,15), 2 arrays with shape (1943,1) and 26 arrays with shape(1943,15)
`fanmap1D` consists of 22 arrays of shape(1,15).

I tried to use `pd.DataFrame`, but I do not know how to read so many arrays.

I expect to read all arrays and convert them to numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the keys of the `mat` dictionary and convert each array to a NumPy array. One way to do is as below:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import numpy as np

mat = loadmat("FanMap_data.mat")
fanmap_arrays = {key: np.array(mat['fanmap'][0, 0][key]) for key in mat['fanmap'].dtype.names}
fanmap1D_arrays = {key: np.array(mat['fanmap1D'][0, 0][key]) for key in mat['fanmap1D'].dtype.names}

print("Arrays in 'fanmap':")
for key, value in fanmap_arrays.items():
    print(key, value.shape)

print("\nArrays in 'fanmap1D':")
for key, value in fanmap1D_arrays.items():
    print(key, value.shape)
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: KeyError
'Npc'
  File "FanMap_data_read_sample2.py", line 9, in <dictcomp>
    fanmap_arrays = {key: np.array(mat[key]) for key in mat['fanmap'].dtype.names}
  File "FanMap_data_read_sample2.py", line 9, in <module>
    fanmap_arrays = {key: np.array(mat[key]) for key in mat['fanmap'].dtype.names}
KeyError: 'Npc'

Comment: I have updated my response. It looks like `npc` is one of the keys within the `fanmap` dataset and so to access it, we have iterate over the `fanmap` dictionary rather than its `dtype.names`.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how to do this iteration over the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

```
mat = loadmat("FanMap_data.mat")
fanmap1D_data = mat['fanmap1D']
fanmap1D_type = fanmap1D_data.dtype
print(fanmap1D_type) # to identify the available keys
fanmap1D_ndata = {n: fanmap1D_data[n][0,0] for n in fanmap1D_type.names}
fanmap1D_Npc = fanmap1D_ndata['Npc']
```

fanmap1D_Npc is a numpy array. All other arrays can be read in a similar way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).